# AFNetworking invalid JSON format returned

Tags: objective-c, json, afnetworking-2

I need to query the Yahoo stock query service in an iOS application using AFNetworking. 
The query returns the following result;

```
YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback({"ResultSet":{"Query":"yahoo","Result":[{"symbol":"YHOO","name":"Yahoo! Inc.","exch":"NMS","type":"S","exchDisp":"NASDAQ","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"YHOF.EX","name":"YAHOO","exch":"EUX","type":"S","exchDisp":"EUREX Futures and Options Exchange ","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"YOJ.BE","name":"YAHOO JAPAN","exch":"BER","type":"S","exchDisp":"Berlin","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"YHOO.MX","name":"Yahoo! Inc.","exch":"MEX","type":"S","exchDisp":"Mexico","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"YHO.DU","name":"YAHOO","exch":"DUS","type":"S","exchDisp":"Dusseldorf Stock Exchange ","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"YAHOY","name":"Yahoo Japan Corporation","exch":"PNK","type":"S","exchDisp":"OTC Markets","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"YAHOF","name":"Yahoo Japan Corporation","exch":"PNK","type":"S","exchDisp":"OTC Markets","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"YOJ.SG","name":"YAHOO JAPAN","exch":"STU","type":"S","exchDisp":"Stuttgart","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"YHOO.SW","name":"YAHOO","exch":"EBS","type":"S","exchDisp":"Swiss","typeDisp":"Equity"},{"symbol":"YHO.HM","name":"YAHOO","exch":"HAM","type":"S","exchDisp":"Hamburg","typeDisp":"Equity"}]}})
```

As the you can see, the JSON is not formatted properly. Specifically speaking, the YAHOO.Finance.SymbolSuggest.ssCallback() is not needed and causes the JSON formatter to crash.

Is there a way to tell AFNetworking to kind of skip the text that isn't part of the actual JSON?

Edit: 
Upon @rckoenes request; This is how the webservice is used;
http://www.jarloo.com/yahoo-stock-symbol-lookup/

Comment: If the webservice is return your example it's not return valid JSON. Are your sure you are using it correctly? Can you post a bit more code, like how and were you get the response?

Comment: @rckoenes, I've edited the question with a link to the webservice 'description'. There really isn't much to configure there.

Comment: Custom `responseSerializer` seem like an overkill here. You might want to use `HTTPResponseSerializer` instead. And parse the result yourself. If this is the only (or one of few) API calls you are making then AFNetworking itself might be an overkill for the job.

Comment: Well it looks like this is not a public API, so you might not be allowed to use it. Off course you still can. Just create your own response serializer end before you decode the JSON remove first part with seem simple string replace and remove the last charter. This should return valid JSON.

Comment: Thanks @rckoenes, using a custom response serializer did the trick just fine. If you create an answer with your suggestion about the serializer, I'd be happy to accept it! It was only a couple of lines of code, so not really overkill for the task at hand. At least it doesn't seem that way. Thanks anyways @rokjarc!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it looks like this is not a public API, so you might not be allowed to use it. Off course you still can. Just create your own response serializer end before you decode the JSON remove first part with seem simple string replace and remove the last charter. This should return valid JSON.